# Default select value not displaying in vue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, html-select

Hi all I'm not able to select a default value for the select dropdown on `v-model="selected_fields[item]"`. I've run the gauntlet of articles but I'm only able to get it to work on a simple select dropdown I have below for `v-model="selected"` when I set it to "". For all intensive purposes, the application works with the mapped fields that I need to save. Its just showing a default value `Choose Data Field` to the user that I'm getting stuck on.

[image]

```
@file_fields = ["Event",
 "First Name",
 "Last Name",
 "Company",
 "Job Title",
 "Ticket",
 "Mobile number",
 "Prefix (Mr., Mrs., etc.)",
 "Industry",
 "Google+ Page",
 "Skype ID",
 "Twitter Handle",
 "Job Function",
 "Work Phone Number",
 "Email Address",
 "Profile Image",
 "Linkedin page",
 "Facebook page",
 "Date of Birth",
 "Street Address",
 "City",
 "State",
 "Zip Code",
 "Country",
 "Company Website",
 "Work Phone"]

@default_selected = Hash[@file_fields.map{ |x,i| [x, ''] }]

<div id="mapping">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in file_fields" class="row mapping-field">
    <div class="col-6">
      <select v-model="selected_fields[item]" class="form-control select">
        <option value="" disabled>Choose Data Field</option>
        <option v-for="(value, key, index) in mapped_fields" v-bind:value="key">{{value}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <table>
        <% if @header %>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                {{item}}
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        <% end %>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-if="preview_data[0][item]">
            <td>
              {{preview_data[0][item]}}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr v-else>
            <td>
              N/A
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr v-if="preview_data[1][item]">
            <td>
              {{preview_data[1][item]}}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr v-else>
            <td>
              N/A
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" v-on:click="saveMapping" v-bind:disabled="isSelected">Next</button>
</div>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#mapping',
    data: {
      selected_fields: <%= raw @default_fields.to_json %>,
      mapped_fields: {
        first_name:          'First Name',
        last_name:           'Last Name',
        job_title:           'Job Title',
        email:               'Email',
        company_agency_name: 'Company/Agency Name',
        address_1:           'Address',
        city:                'City',
        state:               'State',
        zip_code:            'Zip Code',
        main_phone:          'Phone',
        website:             'Website'
      },
      preview_data: <%= raw @preview_data.to_json %>,
      file_fields: <%= raw @file_fields.to_json %>
    },
    computed: {
      isSelected: function () {
        return _.isEmpty(this.selected_fields);
      }
    },
    methods: {
      saveMapping: function() {
        this.$http.post('/order/<%= @uuid %>/save_field_mapping', { selected_fields: this.selected_fields }).then(function (response) {
          window.location.href = response.body.next_path;
        }, function (response) {
          console.log('error:', response.body);
        });
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

**UPDATED**

updated code to working example. Needed to remap @file_fields to hash so each key would have value of "". Then assigned to selected_fields. Originally it was set to {}. Thanks to @daniloisr for the inspiration!

Comment: Your `<select>` is right, so you are missing something through your whole code. Try debugging it part-by-part extracting this code into smaller pieces. Here is a example of a working part https://codesandbox.io/s/o9wkyvj71y?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue

Comment: Thanks @daniloisr thats the example I needed. I was able to now dynamically set all the selected fields from file fields. I just mapped file_fields to a hash that set them all to ''. `@default_selected = Hash[@file_fields.map{ |x,i| [x, ''] }]` Now `selected_fields: @default_selected`

Answer (score 1):

Your `selected_fields` property doesn't contain any of the drop down options, so it won't select any by default. Pass the `key` you wish to use by default to the `v-select`.

Here's an [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8nobboyg/13/).

Comment: Thanks! the problem is that these fields within file_fields can be different depending on what file is uploaded. So I need to find a way to set them all as null when the page loads. I can't set selected_fields and pick just one field to null or ''. It has to be dynamically set depending on what was passed in from file_fields. Thats why v-model references 'item' which is from file_fields. v-model="selected_fields[item]"

Answer (score 0):

this is how i like to do it:

```
//html

<select :value="selectedProjectManager" @input="(val)=>{this.handleNameChange(val.target.value)}">
        <option disabled selected value="">Choose Name</option>
        <option :key="pm.UserId" v-for="pm in projectManagers" :value="pm.UserId">{{pm.FirstName}}</option>
</select>


//JS

data () {
      return {
        selectedProjectManager: null,
        projectManagers: [someListOfManagers]
      }
    },
methods: { 
  handleNameChange (val) {
    this.selectedProjectManager = val
  }
},
```